# Spring security returns WWW-Authenticate header and shows http basic window when httpBasic is disabled

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I have security configuration for my webflux server:

```
    @Bean
    fun httpTestFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().access(authManager)
            .and().cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().disable()

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): ReactiveUserDetailsService {
        val user: UserDetails = User.builder()
            .username(userName)
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build()
        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user)
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean("CustomAuth")
    fun authManager(): 
    ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext> {
        return ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext> { mono, context ->
            val request = context.exchange.request
            val mutateExchange = context.exchange.mutate()

            val token = request.headers[AUTHORIZATION] ?: throw 
            AccessDeniedException(ERROR_MESSAGE)

            mono
                // go to other service to check token
                .then(webClient.checkToken(token.first().toString()))
                .doOnError {
                    throw AccessDeniedException(ERROR_MESSAGE)
                }
                .cast(ResponseEntity::class.java)
                .map { it.body as AuthDto }
                .doOnNext { auth ->
                    mutateExchange.request {
                        it.header(USER_ID, auth.userId.toString())
                        it.header(AUTH_SYSTEM, auth.authSystem)
                    }
                }
                .map { AuthorizationDecision(true) }
        }
    }
```

As you can see httpBasic() option is disabled. When I go to any secure url, browser shows http basic window. Then I can enter valid or INVALID login and password and if authManager returns good result authentication will be successful or 401 will thrown in other case and auth window in browser will reopen.

Why it happens? Is it bug?

P.S. Spring boot version 2.5.5

Comment: Why are you not using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? That is the way Ive always configured my matchers. Im not sure about `SecurityWebFilterChain`. By the way, the question is a duplicate. You may want to change the premise before someone flags.

Comment: I also usually used WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but I found approach with SecurityWebFilterChain is better for web flux.

Comment: You are correct by using `SecurityWebFilterChain` in a WebFlux application. `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is only for servlet based applications. Also, note that Spring Security provides a native Kotlin DSL. You can see examples in the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#explicit-webflux-security-configuration) by toggling the "Kotlin" tab. As for the issue, it is likely related to the custom `authManager`. Try removing or simplifying that class and then debugging. If you cannot find a solution please share the code for `authManager`.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana thank you for advice about Kotlin style! I'll try to simplify my authManager and post it here.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana sorry for the long wait. I added the snippet of authManager bean.

Answer (score 0):

The solution helped me:

```
@Bean
fun httpTestFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().access(authManager)
        .and().cors()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint { exchange, _ ->
            val response = exchange.response
            response.statusCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
            response.headers.set(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "None")
            exchange.mutate().response(response)
            Mono.empty()
        }
        .and()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout().disable()

    return http.build()
}
```

We need change authenticationEntryPoint in part of status code and disabling HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE. Then return changed response.